# How to retrieve params from GET HTTP method using javax.ws.rs.* and Glassfish?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I just installed Glassfish V2 on my local machine just to play around with it.

I was wondering if there is a way to retrieve a param passed in by the GET HTTP method.

For instance,

```
http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/resources/helloWorld?name=ABC
```

How do I retrieve the "name" param in my Java code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
@Path("/helloWorld")
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
@Singleton
public class MyService {
    @GET
    public String getRequest(@QueryParam("name") String name) {
            return "Name was " + name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By putting:

```
@Context
private UriInfo context;
```

in your HelloWorld class, can you access the

```
context.getQueryParameters() ;
```

method to get a map of parameters?

http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-4867/ggrby?a=view

Seems to suggest you can :)